# .Range().Find() throwing 'Object required' error when using String object

Tags: excel, vbscript

This is the first time I'm writing a VBScript code. I am trying to loop through a column to search for a given string and return the address.
Variables 'i' and 'j' are part of the loop, which works fine, hence I'm omitting it out.

```
toSearch = objToExcel.ActiveSheet.PivotTables("MyPivot").RowFields(i).PivotItems(j).Name
If toSearch <> "(blank)" Then
        Set foundRow = objToExcel.ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A20").Find(toSearch)
        MsgBox foundRow.Row
End If
```

I get an error for the line `objToExcel.ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A20").Find(toSearch)` stating `'Object Required: objToExcel.ActiveSheet.Range(...).Find(...)'`.

When I replace the `toSearch` string object with a hard-coded string like `Find("Alex")`, the loop works fine and I get the row number for the string.
Moreover, in the loop, the `toSearch` object is able to get all the strings from the column correctly. When I use the same object in the `Find()`, I get an error.

Any ideas of where I am going wrong?

Comment: As the error is raised in example's firt line, you don't need to test the Find-function within 3rd line at this moment. If your code misses an object in the first line, then I guess the `PivotItems(j)` can not be found. Please check within your i- and j-Loop. You may also compare 'If ... Is Nothing Then' .

Comment: @Asger The item is found in a column (of a pivot table) and I'm using that string object in the 3rd line to search at a different column. The looping does give me the required strings present in the column and hard-coding the `Find()` function with the a string works, too. When I pass the `toSearch` object (which isn't empty), throws an error.

Comment: I suggest to place a `Debug.Print "#" & toSearch & "#"` directly after the first line and then see its last output directly before the orror occurs to recognize the last valid output.

Comment: @Asger I see that the object contains the string I am searching for. And it is indeed the first value in the column. So, `toSearch` is correct.

Comment: I guess its a problem with the declaration of foundRow. I added an answer explaining both variants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you just loop through the range to find the value? Like:

```
For each cell in Range("A2:A20").cells
    if cell.value = toSearch then
        MsgBox cell.Row
        exit for
    end if
next
```

You need to dim cell as range before

Comment: I used this method and for some reason the object was getting assigned correctly. Now my code works.

Answer (score 0):

Still wondering why your workaround works...

Please check if you declared foundRow like `Dim ... as Long`, `Dim ... as Range`, `Dim ... as Variant` (not recommended) or just `Dim ...` (never recommended). In both last cases Excel decides for you and maybe the decision works some code rows before, but not here.

`Range`and `Long` will work, but there are some differences:

```
Dim foundRow as Range
...
Set foundRow = objToExcel.ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A20").Find(toSearch)
If Not foundRow Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox foundRow.Row
Endif
```

or

```
Dim foundRow as Long
...
foundRow = objToExcel.ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A20").Find(toSearch).Row
MsgBox foundRow
```

The first solution is better as you can also handle a non-found.
If it is not found due to whatever reason (Range.Find even doesn't find in hidden or grouped cells), the direct assignment in the second solution raises an error.